# Boolean show null reference exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

i tried many time but all actually i am creating a setting page i mean a setting button where to handle the on and off
in the application class where i extends from the application
it show me the Boolean reference null exception.
the following is the manifest.

```
             <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".ApplicationClass">
    <activity android:name=".SplashScr">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and this is the java class.

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application {
MyService.Reciver  rec;
private Context context;

public Boolean getSoundFX_State() {
    return soundFX_State;
}

public void setSoundFX_State(Boolean soundFX_State) {
    this.soundFX_State = soundFX_State;
}

Boolean soundFX_State;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
super.onCreate();


regster();



  pndng();

    setSoundFX_State(true);
}

protected   void regster()
{
    try {
    rec=new MyService().new Reciver();
    if(soundFX_State==true) {

        registerReceiver(
                rec, new IntentFilter(
                        "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"));
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your call can disconect   automatically", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();


    }
```

and the setting.java class.

```
    public class Setting extends Activity {

    MyService.Reciver  rec;
    private CheckBox c1,c2;
    protected  ApplicationClass app;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.setting);
        app=(ApplicationClass)getApplication();
        c1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        c2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        rec=new MyService().new Reciver();
        if(app.getSoundFX_State())
        {
            c1.setChecked(true);
        }
        else {
            c1.setChecked(false);
        }

        c1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked) {

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "c1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    app.setSoundFX_State(true);

                }
                else {
                    app.setSoundFX_State(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
        c2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"c2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        {

        };

    }



    public  void  chkboxclicked(View view)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the exception. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your "setting.xml" layout file

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Change

```
Boolean soundFX_State;
```

to

```
boolean soundFX_State;
```

**2)**

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();

   setSoundFX_State(true);

    regster();

    pndng();


}
```

Hope this will make sense.

Comment: @princekhan, Happy to help you. :)

Comment: But one more thing in setting activity the checkbox save its state but doesnot work

Comment: Doesnot show any error but not work..actually i want to checkbox off the call doesnot disconnect while its on so the call disconnect auotmatically the method regster as above

Comment: @princekhan, you need to create SingleTon Application class, reason you are creating new instance in SettingsActivity